# Is it possible for Ukraine to hold the parliamentary election in 2023 while in a state of war?

Tags: election, armed-conflict, parliament, ukraine

The Ukranian parliament - Verkhovna Rada - is set to be [reelected in October 2023](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_Ukrainian_parliamentary_election).

Assuming that the Russian invasion persists to that time, what would be the appropriate course of action?

- Do they hold the election as planned? Knowing that a vast number of population cannot vote either because they have fled overseas or are trapped in war-torned eastern region. Not to mention the public administration is probably already too paralyzed to handle the basic logistics (i.e. setting up voting booth, counting votes, etc).
- Alternatively, do they not hold the election and let the current parliament's mendate expire? What happens after that if the country doesn't have a legislature with constitutional mandate?

Comment: We don't know the future, some of the questions here are unanswerable. As for the title, I guess that it is possible to some extent. You describe the difficulties well, but that doesn't mean, one cannot try. From a fundamental point of view I would say that a prolongation of a term because of a war is reasonable but an election where an election is possible, is also something worthwhile to pursue.

Comment: This is really speculative but Ukraine has moved their election before. The 2014 election was supposed to be held in 2015 so it is not unheard of. What the best course of action would be is up to them. Also generally a parliaments mandate expires only when the new parliament gets sworn in. Until then they are transitionally still in power

Answer (score 1):

Under current law 225 members of the Verkhovna Rada are elected by nationwide closed party-list proportional representation with 5% electoral election threshold and the other 225 seats elected in constituencies with a first-past-the-post electoral system in one round (candidate with the highest vote total wins).

During 2019 pariamentary election there were 26 suspended constituencies out of 225 due to the March 2014 annexation of Crimea by Russia and the occupation of parts of Donetsk Oblast and Luhansk Oblast by separatists (since April 2014).

During 2023 parliamentary elections more constituencies will be suspended.

Comment: How did the suspension work exactly? Did both number of seats for the proportional representation part and the first past the post part both got reduced accordingly to the proportion of suspended constituencies or only the direct seats?

Comment: looks like propotional representation part is not reduced

Comment: This would then reduce influence of direct seats if proportional part is not reduced accordingly.

Comment: proportional part is adequately reduced by suspending 11 political parties:
https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/20/ukraine-suspends-11-political-parties-with-links-to-russia

Comment: I don't believe this is the same.